# assigning pipeline result in a variable

Tags: bash, unix, pipeline

I would like to count the number of `*.sav` files in the `$1` folder.
I tried to use the following command but it doesn't work, what is the problem?

```
numOfFiles=`ls $1 | grep -o *\.sav | wc -w`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that *.sav is not a regular expression, it's a glob. You likely wanted to grep for `\.sav`, which you have to escape once for the shell and once again because of the antiquated ``` `` ``` syntax:

```
numOfFiles=`ls $1 | grep -o \\\\.sav | wc -w`
```

Additionally, you should not parse the output of `ls`, and `wc -w` will cause filenames with spaces to be counted multiple times.

A better solution would be to use find:

```
numOfFiles=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sav' | wc -l)
```

For an even better, Bash specific solution, see 1_CR's answer.

Comment: The unquoted `grep` argument would behave the same even if you used `$(...)`

Answer (score 4):

[Do not parse the output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Use bash arrays instead.

```
shopt -s nullglob
sav_files=(*.sav)
echo ${#sav_files[@]}
```

Comment: This will give you 1 when there are no `.sav` files though (and also, you have spaces around the `=`).

Comment: @thatotherguy, thanks! Fixed the spaces and added in `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 1):

Don't want search hypothetical problems in file counting, but parsing output from `ls` can be sometimes wrong idea. Try it yourself, create a file:

```
touch 'aa bb
cc.sav'
```

so, create file with `space` and `newline` in its name. Usually any `ls` parsing will fail.

The 1_CR's solution is NICE and ELEGANT.

If you for some reason don't like it, you can use `find` and don't use `wc` because `wc` for example fails is the last line doesn't contain newline. (wc don't count lines but `\n` chars.

The next will give correct answer:

```
numOfFiles=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.sav -print0 | grep -zc .)
```

the `find` with `-print0` prints all found files "zero ended", and `grep -z` can read like zero delimited "lines". the `-c` simple count found lines for the pattern `.` (any char)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong, `*` is a repetition operator to `grep` but you don't specify what to repeat.

Anyway, the `grep` is unnecessary; just specify the pattern as a shell glob.

```
numOfFiles=`ls "$1"/*.sav | wc -l`
```

Note the quotes around `$1` and the use of line count rather than word count; `wc -w` would return a count of two for `underscore_filename`.

If you do use `grep` for something, it's usually a good idea to put the search pattern in single quotes, so you don't have to backslash-escape shell metacharacters. (Even with the backslash, your pattern would end up unescaped because the shell eats one level of escapes in unquoted strings.)

If you have any matches on `*.sav` in the current directory, the unquoted regex would be expanded as a glob by the shell, and produce interesting results which could be very hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend using quotes around the variables to prevent spaces being a problem.

And additionally, `wc -l` is a better solution since it counts lines instead of words (files with spaces might count twice).

So try this instead:

```
numOfFiles=$(ls -1 "$1/"*.sav | wc -l)
```

Comment: If you quote the glob, it won't expand. Use `"$1"/*.sav`

Comment: Very true, completely forgot about that :P